# Run a script when Dark Mode changes

Tags: dark-mode

How does one register a script to run when the system appearance changes between dark and light? Is there a way to register a Launch Agent? Or have a daemon that gets a notification?

Comment: I really want this as well. Many applications don't quite fully support dark mode. For example, I want Terminal.app to change themes on Light/Dark mode. I wrote [a swift script](https://gist.github.com/sj26/66871cc0c7d856402015f8810771d068) which runs in the background, listens to `AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification`, and uses apple script (sort of) to change the terminal theme. I think it could be triggered by the change via launchd, but seems to need signed entitlements. It would be much easier if there was a way to specify a apple script handler to run when dark mode changes.

Comment: Thanks @sj26! Here is my take on a daemon that runs a command when Dark Mode changes. [dark-mode-notifier](https://github.com/mnewt/dotemacs/blob/master/bin/dark-mode-notifier)